# How do I determine branch name or id in webhook push event?

Tags: github, webhooks

I was ecstatic when I got a simple webhook event listener working with GitHub push events on my Azure site, but I realize now I'm not seeing the branch name or id in the json payload (example here https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)

I thought maybe "tree_id" would be it, but it doesn't seem to be. I couldn't find any info about this in GitHubs's doc. Maybe I need to take one of the id's from the event and make another api call to get the branch? The reason for this is I want to be able to link GitHub push events with my app portfolio, which has branches defined. So, the push events are a way to see code change activity on my different apps -- and knowing the branch is therefore important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote to GitHub support, and they told me that the branch name is part of the "ref" element in the root of the json payload. When parsing from a JToken object called `jsonBody`, the C# looks like this

```
var branchName = jsonBody["ref"].ToString().Split('/').Last();
```

For example in "refs/heads/master", the branch name is "master"

Comment: the branch name can have a '/' character in it so you may need to rework parsing the `ref`

Comment: After reading this https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs, I see that the branch name is anything after "refs/heads" -- no splitting necessary

Comment: Another question I knew I'd feel stupid for not knowing the answer too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay closer look on WEBHOOK response mainly. Here is the trick for JSONPATH ( at-least what I did with my jenkins job):

1. first read your webhook whole response with character "$". You can catch it is some variable like:

   $webhookres='$'

   echo $webhookres
2. Once you have response printed, copy it and paste here: https://jsonpath.com/
3. Now create your pattern. For example if you want **branch** name (if event is push):

> $.ref
>   [image]

Once you have the branch name( it will have extra string with /), simply trim the unwanted part using *awk* or *cut* (linux commands).

4. You are not limited to this only. All you need to work on pattern and you can make use of this approach for getting other values as well like, author, git repo url  etc. and then these can be used in your automation further.
5. even if you are using any other platform like Azure, JSONPATH concept will be same. because as suggested in accepted answer, **"jsonBody["ref"]", it is equivalent to $.ref**, as altogether you have to identify the PATTERN ( as here PATTERN is ***'ref'***)

Comment: I'm already familiar with the webhook response. Your answer doesn't tell me how to isolate the branch name. The `ref` is more than the branch name. You tell me to "trim the unwanted" part of the `ref`, but how do I know what's "unwanted." That is the question I'm asking.

Comment: Like I said, once you have .ref output which is "ref/head/master", so you need to trim unwanted part which is "ref/head/". Branch name will be anything only after "ref/head". So just trim that and you will be left with branch name"master". Other wise, just filter out the last part of the response. Eg., in below response last part is filtered as below:                         
                                                                                             var branchName = jsonBody["ref"].ToString().Split('/').Last()