# How to setup automatic pull for a particular branch in source tree or by using git hooks when a new commit is pushed

Tags: git, webhooks, atlassian-sourcetree

I have cloned the required bitbucket repo in a local workstation. If there is any commit on the particular remote branch, I want it to pull automatically the latest changes. Do we have an option in source tree to set automatic git pull if there is a code change in the remote git repository for a particular branch?

Any other possible workaround is also is welcomed...!

Answer (score 0):

Git has "hooks", actions that can be executed after other actions. What you seem to be looking for is "post-receive hook". In the github admin, you can set up a post-receive url that will be hit (with a payload containing data about what was just pushed) everytime somebody pushes to your repo.

For what it's worth, I don't think auto-pull is a good idea -- what if something wrong was pushed to your branch ? I'd use a tool like capistrano (or an equivalent) for such things.
referenced from: [Git: auto pull from repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the remote side (the one hosting your git repository)

Both [Atlassian BitBucket Cloud](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-and-trigger-a-webhook-tutorial/), [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks) or [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) allows you to define a webhook on that rpeository, allowing you locally to *listen* to hook events, like a push.

Your listener can then [extract from the JSON payload the branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115109/6309).
And, if the name matches the branch you want to monotor, do a `git pull`.